# Pearson's Correlation Always Giving Zero Correlation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pearson-correlation, recommendation-engine

I'm playing with Toby Segaram's recommendation code. [Found here so you can try it out.](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596529321/blob/master/PCI_Code%20Folder/chapter2/recommendations.py)

I noticed something strange about his Pearson correlation code that I'm not sure if it's a bug or a natural part of pearson. Take this line of his code:

```
'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

And change it to:

```
'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.0,'You, Me and Dupree':4.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

(i.e. all ratings for Toby are identical.) Suddenly every single correlation is zero and you get no results back. Why would that be?

I'm still playing with it, so I may end up answering my own question if no one else can.

Update: Is it because pearson's fits a line and in this case Toby causes the line to be vertical for everyone? How does one fix this? Do you put a little bit of noise on each rating?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually pretty obvious in retrospect. Pearson correlation uses a line. But in this case, the ratings are all identical, so the line is vertical which means its slope is undefined.

This is a natural problem with Pearson Correlation. I decided to just use Euclidean distance instead and this worked perfectly.